# add icon to Magento additional info table

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I want to show an icon (png) in my product's additional info table.
This code should work while filling the product information (a text box attribute). But it doesn' :(

```
<img src="{{media url='wysiwyg/infortis/fortis/icons/checkmark.png'}}" />
```

You can see what I want from the picture below:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure that the attribute has the allow html on frontend enabled?   Go to catalog -> Attributes -> attributes.  It's one of the options when creating / editing an attribute.

Comment: Yes. The code was the problem. It seems just direct urls work.

Answer (score 0):

Just direct URLs work in this case.

```
<img src="http://...">
```